# How does np.multiply work?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement np.multiply in Java and I am confused about what it is actually doing. The documentation simply states it does element-wise multiplication. It does not match any mathematical matrix product I can find. It partially matches the element-wise Hadamard product but doesn't need the same number of rows and columns. Does anyone know what mathematical product np.multiply performs and have any more information into EXACTLY how it is working?

Here are the different outputs I've been getting. These seem like very different functionality.

```py
a = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[2,3]])
b = np.array([[2,3,4]])
print(np.multiply(a,b))
#output
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]]]
```

and

```py
a = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])
b = np.array([[2,3,4]])
print(np.multiply(a,b))
#output
[[2 3 4]
 [4 6 8]]
```

Comment: Your first array `a` is a one-dimensional numpy array of type "object" containing regular python lists.  That's because two-dimensional numpy arrays must all have the same number of columns, but when you create `a`, the last list is `[2, 3]`, which has a different number of elements than the previous two.  Numpy is too clever here; instead of raising an error, it figures you know what you're doing.  Try your example again with `a = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 3, 4]])`.  (P.S.  Style suggestion: there is no need for the semicolons.)

Comment: Try `[2,3]*4` in an interpreter - that is a normal Python operation, not a mathematical one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's doing elementwise multiplication just like the documentation says.  note, in your first example,

```
a = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[2,3]])
b = np.array([[2,3,4]])
```

You have an array of objects (lists) because all of the sub-lists don't have the same length.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[2,3]])
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

So when you multiply them, you're multiplying a list by an integer -- which what you got in the result.

e.g. if `c = np.multiply(a, b)`, then:

```
c[0] == [1, 1, 1] * 2
c[1] == [2, 2, 2] * 3
c[2] == [2, 3] * 4
```

So far, we see that multiplying arrays of the same shape produces the [Handamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). What about when they aren't the same shape? In the case, numpy tries to "broadcast" them to the same shape.  The rules can be somewhat complex, so I won't try to reproduce them here, but they can be found at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html.  Scalar-array multiplication works the same as scalar-matrix multiplication works in mathematics.  For arrays which aren't the same shape, the trailing dimensions must match and the array with fewer dimensions is repeated as many times as necessary to fill out the missing dimensions and then the Handamard product is performed.

e.g.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
b = np.array([3, 2, 1])
c = np.array([[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]])
```

In this case, `a * b` and `a * c` will give the same result.

---

Obviously, the way I'm describing it isn't the way it's implemented (that would be seriously inefficient), but it helps as a way of thinking about it.

---

Comment: Is their mathematics on array array multiplication such as the Handamard product

Comment: @user4485835 -- For "matrices" of the same shape, it's the Handamard product.  If the matrices _aren't_ the same shape, numpy tries to [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the arrays to the same shape.

Comment: Just as an additional note, when using numpy arrays the * operator will always produce the same output as multiply(). The multiply() function only needs to be used if you are working with numpy or scipy matrices (which are different from numpy arrays) if you want elementwise multiplication.